# Create report using by union query

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables `SALM(Sales table)` having filed `BillNo,Date,Amount,CusId`   and `CUSMAS(Customer table)` having `ID,CustomerName`.I Want to create a report(between date) having Date on top and Sales details(from SALM) of that date below then Total sales Amount of that date below.

Inputs:From Date and To Date

I have tried this query:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT SALM.INVDATE AS RES1,'' AS RES2 ,'' AS RES3 FROM SALM 
 WHERE SALM.INVDATE BETWEEN #01-Jan-2018# AND #01-Mar-2019# ORDER BY 
 SALM.INVDATE) UNION (SELECT SALM.ORDNO AS RES1, ACCMAS.ACCNAME AS RES2,'' 
AS RES3 FROM SALM INNER JOIN ACCMAS ON SALM.CUSTCODE = ACCMAS.ID WHERE 
SALM.INVDATE BETWEEN #01-Jan-2018# AND #01-Mar-2019# ORDER BY SALM.INVDATE 
UNION select SUM(SALM.AMOUNT) AS RES1, sum(SALM.TAX) AS RES2, 
sum(SALM.NTVALUE) AS RES3 FROM SALM WHERE SALM.INVDATE 
BETWEEN #01-Jan-2018# AND #01-Mar-2019# group by SALM.INVDATE );
```

But the result is not getting in the format I needed

Report format is as shown in picture

[image]

Comment: You should tell us what have you already tried. It would be easy to help you this way.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your picture did not come through, but in any case you should include sample data for both tables and also show the expected output.

Comment: I have tried below query.
(SELECT DISTINCT SALM.INVDATE AS RES1,'' AS  RES2 ,'' AS RES3
FROM SALM WHERE SALM.INVDATE BETWEEN #01-Jan-2018# AND #01-Mar-2019# ORDER BY SALM.INVDATE)
UNION  
(SELECT  SALM.ORDNO AS RES1, ACCMAS.ACCNAME AS RES2,'' AS RES3
FROM SALM INNER JOIN ACCMAS ON SALM.CUSTCODE = ACCMAS.ID WHERE SALM.INVDATE BETWEEN #01-Jan-2018# AND #01-Mar-2019#   ORDER BY SALM.INVDATE
UNION select  SUM(SALM.AMOUNT) AS RES1, sum(SALM.TAX) AS RES2, sum(SALM.NTVALUE) AS RES3
FROM SALM WHERE SALM.INVDATE BETWEEN #01-Jan-2018# AND #01-Mar-2019# group by SALM.INVDATE );

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output

Comment: picture cleared out my mind :) Too Broad

Comment: Saber, include what you tried in your question. not in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this in only one SQL-Expression.

When you use T-SQL (MSSSQL) then you can use this expression for one given date.

```
SELECT '' AS 'Bill No.', CONCAT('Date: ', '03.04.2018') AS 'Customer Name', '' AS 'Amount'
UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, BillNo), CustomerName, CONVERT(varchar, Amount) 
FROM SALM LEFT JOIN CUSMAS ON SALM.CusId = CUSMAS.Id WHERE Date = '3.4.2018'
UNION ALL
SELECT '', 'Cash Total', 'don''t know what you want in herer'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '', 'Credit Total', 'don''t know what you want in herer'
UNION ALL
SELECT '', 'Day Total', CONVERT(varchar, SUM(Amount)) 
FROM SALM LEFT JOIN CUSMAS ON SALM.CusId = CUSMAS.Id WHERE Date = '3.4.2018'
```

Then you could do this in C# throu a loop of all possible `DateTimes` and use the expresion for each `DateTime`.

When you just want to call one SQL function, then you need to create a `FUNCTION` which returns a table. You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql).

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMyReport(@from DATETIME, @to DATETIME)
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
BillNo VARCHAR,
CustomerName VARCHAR,
Amount VARCHAR
)
BEGIN
    --FILL YOUR TABLE HERE
END;
```